# Use of verb "to commence"

Tags: verbs

I know the verb is only used in formal language, but we're having a discussion on the use of it in the following sentence:

"The discharge of the cargo was commenced at 9 o'clock"

OR

"The discharge of the cargo commenced at 9 o'clock"

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think it is only used in formal language?  It is a very common word.

Comment: Related. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69766/replacing-begin-by-commence

Comment: Thanks Chenmunka, and which sentence is correct? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use it in law. You may say both :

- *Commenced* is the simple preterit form which is the more usual ;
- *Was commenced* is another past composed form : "the discharge of the cargo **was commenced** at 9 AM *when* customs' team went onboard for the sanitary inspection."

Comment: Yes, both are fine: the difference is between an active and intransitive use *(commenced)* and a passive transitive one *(was commenced),* both alike in the simple past or preterit tense.